# Дублирование кода WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, как избежать дублирования кода на формах, если логика заполнения и обработки данных типовая, отличаются только передаваемые типы? 
Например, обработка двойного клика в DataGrid типовая, отличие в самом элементе с которым работаем (Задумка: можно передавать сам объект в метод) и тип данных, которые обрабатываем:

```
    private void DoubleClickRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgStagesView.SelectedItem != null && dgStagesView.SelectedItem is View_BalanceStage)//Тут соответственно указываем элемент на форме
        {
            Win_DetailsOfStage stagesForm = new Win_DetailsOfStage((View_BalanceStage)dgStagesView.SelectedItem); //Тут изменяется тип формы, с которой мы будем работать

            if (stagesForm != null && stagesForm.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                FillDataGrid();//обновление данных 
            }
        }
    }
```

и

```
    private void DoubleClickRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgExecutorsView.SelectedItem != null && dgExecutorsView.SelectedItem is View_ExecutorsOfStages)
        {
            Win_Executors executorsForm = new Win_Executors((View_ExecutorsOfStages)dgExecutorsView.SelectedItem);

            if (executorsForm != null && executorsForm.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                FillDataGrid();
            }
        }
    }
```

Также есть аналогичные/схожие куски кода по обработке нажатий на кнопки/элементы.
Буду очень признательна если поможете разобраться как оптимизировать код,  например, подскажите название паттерна или пример как подойти к реализации MVVM.

Comment: Приведите пример двух типовых операций, я б посоветовал использовать функции с типом `<T>`, но не уверен что вам подойдет

Comment: сам объект уже передается в метод это первый аргумент просто приведи к нужному типу например   ((Button)sender) или любой другой тип  и + плюс для  можно юзать 1 метод для всех кликов по всем клеткам и например для всех кнопок 1 обработчик нажатия как уже говорил

Comment: это самый простой вариант

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то можно вынести в класс (может даже статический) и обращаться к методу, передавая объект и тип?

Comment: Мне кажется тут применение общей модели и привязка ее к компонентам, но я никак не могу понять детали этой реализации. MVVM для этой цели подходит? Как передать в вызов делегата еще и параметры?

Comment: @Spiffo, если следовать MVVM, то можно сделать логику через привязку команд. И можно так же внутрь команды пулять данные, которые получать на стороне VM и обрабатывать.